# How to reload the tree store for tree grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

So I used sencha ext js tree grid for the need of my project. I'm having difficulty finding the answer on how to reload the tree store with different data. thanks

Comment: Have you managed to load it properly the first time?

Comment: I've faced the same problem and haven't found the good solution yet. But my problem is in reloading the one node data only.

Comment: You can try to use this solution (but it's not working for me): `refreshNode.removeAll(false);
this.getMyTreeStore().load({
 node : refreshNode
});`

Answer (score 0):

TreeGrid is tree therefore you have to refresh it as tree
if you use AsyncTreeNode (with loaders) then you can use 'reload' method of the async mode:

```html
TreeGrid.getRootNode().reload();
```